# VSCode does not show errors before building

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, visual-c++

I use VSCode(code editor, not IDE) for C++ with only Microsoft's C++ extension and today I have encountered a problem here. When I write the wrong syntax, the "PROBLEMS" panel does not show errors. It only shows errors on building the code. Earlier that wasn't the case. How do I fix this ?

Before building:
[image]

After building:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Completely normal for C++ development, What is there C++17 on your program?

Comment: If attempting to use MS's C++ environment, you have to open VS Code from a dev terminal. Even then it won't really behave as you would expect.

Comment: @rioV8 But earlier I used to get errors if there was wrong syntax while writing the code. Now errors only occur after building it.

Comment: @sweenish  You can see in the pics that I have opened a developer powershell in the background. I always use developer command prompt or powershell for opening VSCode, else the code never builds cause the compiler is not in the path.

Comment: @DivijManchanda No, I can't. I just see Powershell is open. It's also worth noting that questions with pictures are not how you are supposed to ask questions. Please read [ask] and [mre] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 25):

I got that error by **Disable error squiggles**. If you don't reach that error in my case, don't read anymore.

[image]

After ignoring, I got your problem:

[image]

To fix this, open settings.json file:

[image]

Scroll to the end, then set "C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": from **Disabled** to **Enabled**.
[image]

Comment: Also accessible through the Command Center (F1): ">C/C++: Enable Error Squiggles"

Answer (score 5):

After reading the question, and the comments, my understanding is that you want `Visual Studio Code` to tell you when you make a mistake on the sintax, without having to compile the project.

What could be wrong is your `C++` IntelliSense, which is odd because it comes in bundle with the C/C++ extension from Microsoft. The extension itself might be disabled, corrupted during an aborted update, or uninstalled.

Have you tried the good old and helpful *uninstall* and *reinstall* the extension? That normally fixes my problems with extensions in Visual Studio and VS Code

Comment: I tried reinstalling the extension, but it is still not working for me.

Answer (score 3):

Note: You have to install the extension first: **C/C++ IntelliSense, debugging, and code browsing extension**

This is because the **C/C++ IntelliSense, debugging, and code browsing extension** does not know about the current project.

Navigate to **View | Command Palette**, enter and select C/C++ Build and debug active file: Select
Project, and then select the correct project that you want to work with.

This will help you see the problems as you create your code without requiring you to run it.

The extension has to know that it is allowed to continuously check your code.

I hope this helps you in the future with other extensions too...

Answer (score 2):

Try and close your current folder and open a different folder. Then come back to your original folder. This worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

It worked in my case by just enabling Error Squiggles.

To do this, Open VS Code, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>,
then, in the search bar, search for "enable error squiggles" and click on it.

[image: Here is one screenshot of search bar for reference]

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with C# so this is how I ended up here.

Managed to fix it by changing the sln file of the project root directory where:

> Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "housesapi", "backend\HouseApi\HouseApi.csproj", "{C0FF5955-650A-4458-A35C-50477850354E}"

was incorrect.

After I pointed it to the proper route everything worked and the errors were shown.
Here I used the dev kit for C#, a VS Code extension.